# I can't apply a rule for a map field in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I try to verify that the values entered by the user in the likes field are zero:

```
request.resource.data.likes.size() == 0
```

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{post}
    {
      allow read :if request.auth != null;
      allow create : if request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider != 'anonymous'
      && request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid
      && request.resource.data.size() == 8
      && request.resource.data.hasOnly(['withPhoto','uid', 'text', 'tags','imageUrl', 'imageThump', 'comments', 'likes'])
      && request.resource.data.likes.size() == 0;
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try it through the app it gives me the following error:

> [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

When I deleted the line `request.resource.data.likes.size() == 0` it worked.

This code describes how I add the poss:

```
      Set<String> tags = _getTags(postText.toString().split(' '));
      FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      await firestore.doc("posts/" + uuid).set({
                "uid" : uid,
                "likes":{},
                "comments":{},
                "tags": tags.toList(),
                "text": postText,
                "imageUrl": imageUrl,
                "imageThump": imageThumpUrl,
                "withPhoto": withPhoto
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been struggling with your question for about half an hour. And I'm sorry to say but I can't find an answer for you. But I do want to give you some advice.

There is a really nice feature in the Firestore rules section that's called 'Rules Playground'. This is the place where you can test your rules and see exactly where your rule denies your access.

I hope you can figure it out, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was in another rules

```
request.resource.data.size() == 8
&& request.resource.data.hasOnly(['withPhoto','uid', 'text', 'tags','imageUrl', 'imageThump', 'comments', 'likes'])
&& request.resource.data.likes.size() == 0;
```

it must to be:

```
&& request.resource.data.keys().size() == 8
      && request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(['withPhoto','uid', 'text', 'tags','imageUrl', 'imageThump', 'comments', 'likes'])
&& request.resource.data.likes.keys().size() == 0;
```